# How to create a custom function properly in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, function, variables

I have created a custom function and I am getting this error. I dont think there is a "parse error" in my script.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '&' or T_VARIABLE in C:\wamp\www\web template\test.php on line 8
```

---

```
<?php
require('global script/php/dbConnect.php');

$varName = 'sd';

echo checkDBDuplicate('account_list', 'memberID', $varName);

function checkDBDuplicate(tableName, dbFieldName, variableName) 
{
    $tableName = tableName;
    $dbFieldName = dbFieldName;
    $variableName = variableName;

    $searchDuplicate = mysql_query('
        SELECT $dbFieldName
        FROM $tableName
        WHERE $dbFieldName = $variableName
        ') or die(mysql_error());
    $countRow = mysql_num_rows($searchDuplicate);

    return $countRow;
}
?>
```

The purpose of this script is to test if I can use a variable in a SELECT statement.

Comment: what is on line 8 of test.php

Comment: in your sql statement make sure to escape the strings using `mysql_real_escape_string`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variables should have a `$` prefix. so

```
function checkDBDuplicate(tableName, dbFieldName, variableName) {
```

is wrong, make it

```
function checkDBDuplicate($tableName, $dbFieldName, $variableName) {
```

obviously, further on the same is true, so:

```
$tableName = tableName;
$dbFieldName = dbFieldName;
$variableName = variableName;
```

needs the same treatment

Comment: Ah thank you. It's working now. I thought I wasn't doing anything wrong because Javascript didn't need "var" in the function parameters.

Comment: Check. Just a remark: 'var' doesn't mean "i'm making a variable here"! It is never actually needed to declare a variable, it means "this variable should be global". Therefore it's logical it shouldn't go in a function. You could compare it with the php keyword "global", which also never goes into a function declaration.  The `$` means "a variable starts here" in php. There is no equivalent in Javascript, but certainly not the `var` keyword :)

Answer (score 3):

```
function checkDBDuplicate(tableName, dbFieldName, variableName) {
```

Should be

```
function checkDBDuplicate($tableName, $dbFieldName, $variableName) {
```

and iside the function body:

```
$tableName = $tableName;
$dbFieldName = $dbFieldName;
$variableName = $variableName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function should be like this:

```
<?php
require('global script/php/dbConnect.php');

$varName = 'sd';

echo checkDBDuplicate('account_list', 'memberID', $varName);

function checkDBDuplicate($tableName, $dbFieldName, $variableName) {
     $tableName = $tableName;
     $dbFieldName = $dbFieldName;
     $variableName = $variableName;
     $searchDuplicate = mysql_query("
     SELECT $dbFieldName
     FROM $tableName
     WHERE $dbFieldName = $variableName
     ") or die(mysql_error());
     $countRow = mysql_num_rows($searchDuplicate);
     return $countRow;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The variables do not need to be assigned again !!!

Also some ' and ` are missing the the SQL query.

```
<?php
require('global script/php/dbConnect.php');

$varName = 'sd';

echo checkDBDuplicate('account_list', 'memberID', $varName);

function checkDBDuplicate($tableName, $dbFieldName, $variableName) {

     $searchDuplicate = mysql_query("
                        SELECT `$dbFieldName`
                       FROM `$tableName`
                      WHERE `$dbFieldName` = '$variableName'
                      ") or die(mysql_error());
     $countRow = mysql_num_rows($searchDuplicate);
     return $countRow;
}
?>
```